How to access (EntryAssemblyName).Properties.Settings in C#
Here is the shared code in many projects by linking:
FileUtil.cs
namespace CommonLibs
{
    internal class FileUtil
    {
        public static bool OpenFile(out string ResultPath, string FileName, string InitialDirectory = null, string Filter = "AllFiles(*.*)|*.*", int? FilterIndex = null, bool CheckFileExists = true, bool CheckPathExists = true)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();


            // get the entry assembly
            var asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            var asmName = asm.GetName().Name;
            var settings = asm.GetType(asmName + ".Properties.Settings");

            // (some code to deal with 'Default' in the settings type : I'm not aware of) 

            // use the 'LastOpenPath' setting for default path 
            InitialDirectory = InitialDirectory ?? settings.Default.LastOpenPath;
            FilterIndex = FilterIndex ?? settings.Default.LastFilterIndex;
            FilterIndex = FilterIndex < 0 ? 1 : FilterIndex;
            FilterIndex = FilterIndex < 0 ? 1 : FilterIndex;

            ofd.FileName = FileName;
            ofd.InitialDirectory = InitialDirectory;
            ofd.Filter = Filter;
            ofd.FilterIndex = FilterIndex.GetValueOrDefault(1);
            ofd.CheckFileExists = CheckFileExists;
            ofd.CheckPathExists = CheckPathExists;

            ResultPath = "";
            ...
        }
    }
}

FileUtil.cs is shared to many projects by simple file linking like below:



Project
Perpose




CommonLibs
Test


Project1
Using


Project2
Using


Project3
Using


...




and this is Settings for the projects :



Name
Tupe
Scope
Value




...





LastOpenPath
string
user
"C:\"


LastFilterIndex
int
user
1


...






I just want to access the shared Properties in the Settings.Default in each project.
I found how to access the Types in the EntryAssembly.(Runtime Assembly?)
But I couldn't find how to get the 'Default' and their members.
How can I do that?

I solved it myself.
public static bool OpenFile(out string ResultPath, string FileName, string InitialDirectory = null, string Filter = "すべてのファイル(*.*)|*.*", int? FilterIndex = null, bool CheckFileExists = true, bool CheckPathExists = true)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();


    // get the executing assembly
    var asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    var asmName = asm.GetName().Name;
        //GetExecutingAssembly();
    var settings = asm.GetType(asmName + ".Properties.Settings");
    var Default_Type = settings.GetProperty("Default");
    var Default = Default_Type.GetValue(null);
    var LastOpenPath_PropInfo = Default_Type.PropertyType.GetProperty("LastOpenPath");
    var LastFilterIndex_PropInfo = Default_Type.PropertyType.GetProperty("LastFilterIndex");
    var Save_MethodInfo = Default.GetType().GetMethod("Save");

    var LastOpenPath = LastOpenPath_PropInfo.GetValue(Default);
    var LastFilterIndex = LastFilterIndex_PropInfo.GetValue(Default);
    //CommonLibs.Properties.Settings


    // use the 'LastOpenPath' setting for default path 
    InitialDirectory = InitialDirectory ?? LastOpenPath as string;
    FilterIndex = FilterIndex ?? LastFilterIndex as int?;
    FilterIndex = FilterIndex < 0 ? 1 : FilterIndex;

    ofd.FileName = FileName;
    ofd.InitialDirectory = InitialDirectory;
    ofd.Filter = Filter;
    ofd.FilterIndex = FilterIndex.GetValueOrDefault(1);
    ofd.CheckFileExists = CheckFileExists;
    ofd.CheckPathExists = CheckPathExists;

    ResultPath = "";
    
    //show dialog 
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        // return the fullname path only when click 'OK' button
        ResultPath = ofd.FileName;
        FilterIndex = ofd.FilterIndex;
        // reflesh the last path and index infomation

        LastOpenPath_PropInfo.SetValue(Default, ResultPath);
        LastFilterIndex_PropInfo.SetValue(Default, FilterIndex);
        //Settings.Default.LastOpenPath = ResultPath;
        //Settings.Default.LastFilterIndex = FilterIndex.GetValueOrDefault(1);

        Save_MethodInfo.Invoke(Default, null);  
        //Settings.Default.Save();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

It runs, but it's not smart neat. ok.
